# Nginx showing SSL error

Tags: tomcat, nginx, tomcat7, connection

We are using nginx infront of our tomcat. we have an issue having some of our outside clients not able to create successfully connection to our single tomcat instance.

If we have around 7000 connections so 200-300 are lost(never reached to our tomcat)

I cant see anything special in tomcat logs however when I check nginx I see that error repeating itself lots of times:

```
ngx_slab_alloc() failed: no memory in SSL session shared cache "TLSSL"
```

Any idea if this is a lead to the connections problem? how could I solve this?

thanks,
ray.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Configure the `ssl_session_cache` direcive.

> Sets the types and sizes of caches that store session parameters.

Source: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_session_cache

Comment: Yes. but which configuration should I use? any leads?